# Open an entire map with images in Preview on Mac in Java

Tags: java, windows, macos

I am currently programming an application for someone with a great archive of old pictures, images and text documents from his city. I can open every document in a map but how can i open an entire map in Preview on a Mac. Because the program will be used on a Mac and on a Windows pc. In Windows u can go through all images with opening just 1 image but on OS-X that isnt possible. Someone has an idea?

Comment: Can you add some more detail on this? Im not exactly sure what you are trying to do? How do you mean "I can open every document in a map"? or "how can i open an entire map in Preview" What fiel type is this map, what error do you get? If you add all the details we might eb able to help

Comment: well, it's a map which only contains pictures. When you do a right mouseclick in OSX you can choose for the option "open whole map in preview". But how can i make a java program do this?